# How to properly display a product preview page after the product is created using react.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am creating a simple `eCommerce` app where I want to redirect users to a product preview page after they create a product.

I have tried implementing this using `<Redirect />` in my `UploadProduct component`

code snippet below:

```
state = {
            productName: '',
            productSize: '',
            productPrize: '',
            category: '',
            description: '',
             // color: [],
            imageFile: null,
            redirect: false
        };
```

in the render method I then conditionally redirect only if `this.state.redirect` 
is true, which I update after `axios post request` below shows how I implement the redirect.

```
const {redirect} = this.state;

        if(redirect){
            console.log("Im here redirect now", redirect);
            return <Redirect from='/product/new' to='/product/preview' />
        }
```

My `App.js`
State:

```
state = {
        products: [],
        productID: null,
        noProducts: false
    };
```

I update its `state` using:

```
    handleProductCreated = (productID) => {
        this.setState({
            productID //es6
        });
    }
```

which is passed to the `uploadProduct component` as `props` code below:

```
<Route path='/product/new' 
render={(routeProps)=> <UploadProduct {...routeProps} productCreated= {this.handleProductCreated}  /> } />
```

I expect to be redirect when a new product is created to the `product preview page` put I am getting this error message:

```
index.js:1375 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
```

And I'm being redirected to the `/notfound`

Answer (score 0):

what you need is async await. make sure the function in which you are making the API call, that function is using async await. Since you have not posted your API call function. i am assuming few parts and writing the code below in ES6.

```
createProduct = async dataForApi => {
    await makeApiCallForCreatingProduct(dataForApi);
    this.setState({ redirect: true })
};
```